# Store ethereum transaction id (metamask) in php variable

Tags: javascript, php, ethereum, metamask

I'm not used to javascript and I am using the code below to send an ethereum transaction via metamask, and it looks like it is all working fine, I can print the transaction's hash after it is sent with document.write, but can't find a way to store the hash in a php variable to afterwards deal with it in a database and whatever.

I need the value of 'txHash' in a php variable. Would appreciate a lot some help! Thanks

```
sendEthButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ethereum
    .request({
      method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
      params: [
        {
          from: accounts[0],
          to: '< - RECEIVING ACCOUNT - >',
          value: '0xDE0B6B3A7640000',
        },
      ],
    })
.then((txHash) => document.write(txHash))
.catch((error) => console.error);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is executed **before** the browser JavaScript. It's not able to interact with MetaMask, as it doesn't have access to the `window.ethereum` object of the extension.

However, you can use JavaScript [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) function to send the transaction ID (or any other data) from JS to a PHP script.

```
ethereum.request({
    // ...
}).then((txHash) => {
    fetch('/txIdReceiver.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: 'hash=' + txHash,
    })
})
```

Because of the `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, the transaction hash is now available in the `$_POST["hash"]` variable of the PHP script.